# Why does less store its configuration in a binary file?

Tags: configuration, less

I'm just wondering: why does `less` store its configuration in a binary file `.less`, which you have to generate with `lesskey` from the text-file `.lesskey`?

What could be the benefits of this behavior? Speed? But parsing a tiny human-readable configuration file can't take that long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code for `lesskey` says:

```
 * Copyright (C) 1984-2015  Mark Nudelman
```

which gives a hint that performance might have been a factor in deciding to use a compiled configuration file.  Machines were a little smaller and slower 32 years ago.